# "xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp" header file is missing in Xerces 3.2.1

Tags: xerces

I am trying upgrade C++ code, the header file -  is missing in Xerces 3.2.1

```
// platform that the specific makefile should copy over.
//
//  If the next line generates an error then you haven't run ./configure
#include    <xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp>
```